# Using Spark Context To Read Parquet File as RDD(wihout using Spark-Sql Context) giving Exception

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I am trying to read and write Parquet file as RDD using Spark. I cant use Spark-Sql-Context in my current application(It needs a parquet schema in StructType which when I convert from Avro Schema gives me castException in few cases)

So if i try to implement and save Parquet File by overload AvroParquetFormat and Sending ParquetInputFormat to Hadoop To write in following way:

```
def saveAsParquetFile[T <: IndexedRecord](records: RDD[T], path: String)(implicit m: ClassTag[T]) = {
            val keyedRecords: RDD[(Void, T)] = records.map(record => (null, record))
            spark.hadoopConfiguration.setBoolean("parquet.enable.summary-metadata", false)
            val job = Job.getInstance(spark.hadoopConfiguration)
            ParquetOutputFormat.setWriteSupportClass(job, classOf[AvroWriteSupport])
            AvroParquetOutputFormat.setSchema(job, m.runtimeClass.newInstance().asInstanceOf[IndexedRecord].getSchema())
            keyedRecords.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
              path,
              classOf[Void],
              m.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]],
              classOf[ParquetOutputFormat[T]],
              job.getConfiguration
            )
          }
```

This is thowing error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InstantiationException: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord
```

I am calling The function as follows:

```
val file1: RDD[GenericRecord] = sc.parquetFile[GenericRecord]("/home/abc.parquet")
sc.saveAsParquetFile(file1, "/home/abc/")
```

Comment: I've never used that Parquet API before, but it looks like GenericRecord is an interface, not a class. Instead use GenericData.Record from the same package.

Comment: I think you are using a custom spark context for reading the parquet file as Avro GenericRecord. I could not find the method parquetFile[T] (String...paths) in the SparkContext. I found  here https://gist.github.com/eggsby/ce6c1ec5b0281bf96e34, a SparquetContext class that provides both functionalities for reading and writing parquet files.